# XSL transformation when element contains value

Tags: xml, xslt

I winded up doing some xsl transformations on .xml, I managed to do somewhat of what I would like to do, but I can't figure out the rest. This is the .xml content

```
  <Parent1>
    <Parent2>
        <Number>"100"</Number>
        <Name>"SanJose"</Name>
        <Type>"SanJoseExtra"</Type>
        <Adress>Avenue 54</Adress>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <TR5>1</TR5>
        <TR10>0</TR10>
        <Modifier>0</Modifier>
    </Parent2>
    <Parent2>
        <Number>"100"</Number>
        <Name>"SanTropez"</Name>
        <Type>"SanTropezSmall"</Type>
        <Adress>British Cal 3</Adress>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <TR5>1</TR5>
        <TR10>1</TR10>
        <Modifier>0</Modifier>
    </Parent2>
    <Parent2>
        <Number>"101"</Number>
        <Name>"SanJose"</Name>
        <Type>"SanDiegoMedium"</Type>
        <Adress>French Revolution n.n.</Adress>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <TR5>1</TR5>
        <TR10>1</TR10>
        <Modifier>0</Modifier>
    </Parent2>
    <Parent2>
        <Number>"100"</Number>
        <Name>"SanJose"</Name>
        <Type>"SanJoseSmall"</Type>
        <Adress>Avenue 54</Adress>
        <Status>1</Status>
        <TR5>1</TR5>
        <TR10>0</TR10>
        <Modifier>0</Modifier>
    </Parent2>
</Parent1>
```

and I would like to change the Modifier value to 1 if the `<Name>` contains SanJose and the `<Status>` contains 1. So I made something like this to get this output :

```
<xsl:template match="*"> 
            <xsl:copy> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
            </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template> 



    <xsl:template match="XMLLine[contains(./Name,'SanJose') and contains(./Status,'1')]"> 
        <Parent2>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Number" />
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Name" />
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Type" />
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Adress" />
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Status" />
                        <xsl:copy-of select="TR5" />
                        <xsl:copy-of select="TR10" />
                        <Modifier>1</Modifier>
        </Parent2> 
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But then I realized that there is SanJose with status 1 where I also want to change the Modifier to 1, but I don't have anything connecting it other than Name which I know in advance and the  100 which I don't always know in advance because the list goes on.

So to sum it up, the problem I find is that I have common name and status which I can use but I also want to apply it to other nodes containing name SanJose but with the same Number which I can't know in advance.

**EDIT:**
Adding an increment for every occurrence with the same Number. So instead of changing the Modifier to 1 I was trying to make it STATUS1, STATUS2, STATUS3.... and so on. I tried modifying your xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="incre">0</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="matching-parent" match="Parent2[Name='SanJose' and Status=1]" use="Number" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Modifier[key('matching-parent', ../Number)]/text()"> 
<xsl:value-of select="concat('STATUS', $incre+1)" /> 
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, my logic with the $incre fails, because it never increments, it always remains STATUS1.

Comment: I don't understand your question. How did you jump from 1 to 100 in "*but I don't have anything connecting it other than Name which I know in advance and the 100 which I don't always know in advance because the list goes on.*"?  -- Note also that your code does not match your input: there is no `XMLLine` in the input you show.

Comment: the thing is that <Name> is a constant which I know, <Status> is something I can assume and decide whether to let it be deciding factor in the change but the <Number> is a variable that is randomly passed, it's not incremental always as seen in the small part I showed, and that is why I can't assume the <number> in advance, only when I satisfy the <Name> along with the <status> I decided to add the same <Number> if previous nodes were already changed

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot make head or tails out what you're saying. Please edit your question and try to formulate clear rules when should the modifier value be changed to 1. Assume the rules will be followed *literally* by a stupid person who will be doing this manually.

Comment: ok i understand it gets messy, but the main focus is to be able to first change all the nodes where <name> = SanJose and <status> = 1, and then take the <Number> from such cases and change it everywhere else where that <Number> occurs, because that number is the connection that I have between them but I can't know it in advance like I would know in the previous modification (name=SanJose and status=1). I have an idea of creating a variable with the value of <Number> where <name> and <status> are SanJose and 1, but Im not sure on how to set it up and use it after to change the other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> first change all the nodes where `<name>` = SanJose and `<status>` = 1,
>   and then take the `<Number>` from such cases and change it everywhere
>   else where that `<Number>` occurs

If I understand correctly, this could also be expressed as:

1. group all nodes by `Number`;
2. if any member of a group satisfies `[Name='SanJose' and Status='1']`, then change the entire group.

Looking at it this way, you could streamline the solution to:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="matching-parent" match="Parent2[Name='SanJose' and Status=1]" use="Number" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Modifier[key('matching-parent', ../Number)]/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **test input**:

```
<Parent1>
    <Parent2>
        <Number>111</Number>
        <Name>Starter</Name>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <Modifier>0</Modifier>
    </Parent2>
    <Parent2>
        <Number>111</Number>
        <Name>SanJose</Name>
        <Status>1</Status>
        <Modifier>0</Modifier>
    </Parent2>
    <Parent2>
        <Number>222</Number>
        <Name>SanJose</Name>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <Modifier>0</Modifier>
    </Parent2>
    <Parent2>
        <Number>111</Number>
        <Name>Another 1</Name>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <Modifier>0</Modifier>
    </Parent2>
    <Parent2>
        <Number>222</Number>
        <Name>Another 2</Name>
        <Status>1</Status>
        <Modifier>0</Modifier>
    </Parent2>
    <Parent2>
        <Number>111</Number>
        <Name>SanJose</Name>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <Modifier>0</Modifier>
    </Parent2>
</Parent1>
```

produces this **result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parent1>
   <Parent2>
      <Number>111</Number>
      <Name>Starter</Name>
      <Status>2</Status>
      <Modifier>1</Modifier>
   </Parent2>
   <Parent2>
      <Number>111</Number>
      <Name>SanJose</Name>
      <Status>1</Status>
      <Modifier>1</Modifier>
   </Parent2>
   <Parent2>
      <Number>222</Number>
      <Name>SanJose</Name>
      <Status>2</Status>
      <Modifier>0</Modifier>
   </Parent2>
   <Parent2>
      <Number>111</Number>
      <Name>Another 1</Name>
      <Status>2</Status>
      <Modifier>1</Modifier>
   </Parent2>
   <Parent2>
      <Number>222</Number>
      <Name>Another 2</Name>
      <Status>1</Status>
      <Modifier>0</Modifier>
   </Parent2>
   <Parent2>
      <Number>111</Number>
      <Name>SanJose</Name>
      <Status>2</Status>
      <Modifier>1</Modifier>
   </Parent2>
</Parent1>
```

Note especially the last node in the example.

---

### Edit:

If I understand your new requirement correctly, you need to change this:

```
<xsl:template match="Modifier[key('matching-parent', ../Number)]/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="Modifier[key('matching-parent', ../Number)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('STATUS', count(../preceding-sibling::Parent2[key('matching-parent', Number)]) + 1)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, first, thank you for your time and involvement, I understand that data seems messy and that its hard to understand the problem. Your xsl works almost perfect, it affects all the groups but the first node when its the case that the first node with the conditions is in the middle of all of data. So when the nodes already start with the <Name> and <Status> satisfied then it changes all of them, but when the first satisfying condition starts for example in the 26th node somewhere in the middle of all data then the first one doesn't change and the rest change perfectly.

Comment: @user2842773 I am unable to reproduce your issue. I have edited my example so that the group does NOT start with a qualifying node. Does this still work for you?

Comment: Hi, I tried modifying your xsl a bit in order to make the modifier increment. I tried adding a global variable at the top of the document like this <xsl:variable name="incre">1</xsl:variable>, and then using it in the 
<xsl:template match="Modifier[key('matching-parent', ../Number)]/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('STATUS', $incre+1)" />
</xsl:template>
but without luck in regards of the increment.

Comment: @user2842773 I am afraid I don't follow. If this is still within the same question, please edit your question and add further explanations. Otherwise it would be better to post a new one, IMHO.

Comment: Hi michael.hor257k I edited the original question, since it is only an edit regarding your provided xsl which work. Thank you

Comment: @user2842773 "*it is only an edit*" Not quite - but see if the added edit to my answer helps.

Comment: Hi michael.hor257k, Do you think it is possible to test the <status> in this case against multiple different strings using contains() in XSLT1.0. I tried to do it externally from another .xml document but it doesn't seem to work. Also xsl:key doesn't allow me to use variables inside it.

Comment: @user2842773 I suggest you post another question. Or rather clarify your other question on this topic?

Comment: Hi, is it possible to make the count based on the xsl key, in this case Number, so it increments when there is a match but only when the Number changes and not for every node that has a match?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following stylesheet from what I can understand with your question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="SJ" match="Parent2[contains(Name, 'SanJose') and Status = 1]" use="Number"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Modifier">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(preceding-sibling::Name, 'SanJose') 
                                and
                                preceding-sibling::Status = 1">
                    <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="key('SJ', preceding-sibling::Number)">
                    <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it produces:

```
<Parent1>
   <Parent2>
      <Number>"100"</Number>
      <Name>"SanJose"</Name>
      <Type>"SanJoseExtra"</Type>
      <Adress>Avenue 54</Adress>
      <Status>2</Status>
      <TR5>1</TR5>
      <TR10>0</TR10>
      <Modifier>1</Modifier>
   </Parent2>
   <Parent2>
      <Number>"100"</Number>
      <Name>"SanTropez"</Name>
      <Type>"SanTropezSmall"</Type>
      <Adress>British Cal 3</Adress>
      <Status>2</Status>
      <TR5>1</TR5>
      <TR10>1</TR10>
      <Modifier>1</Modifier>
   </Parent2>
   <Parent2>
      <Number>"101"</Number>
      <Name>"SanJose"</Name>
      <Type>"SanDiegoMedium"</Type>
      <Adress>French Revolution n.n.</Adress>
      <Status>2</Status>
      <TR5>1</TR5>
      <TR10>1</TR10>
      <Modifier>0</Modifier>
   </Parent2>
   <Parent2>
      <Number>"100"</Number>
      <Name>"SanJose"</Name>
      <Type>"SanJoseSmall"</Type>
      <Adress>Avenue 54</Adress>
      <Status>1</Status>
      <TR5>1</TR5>
      <TR10>0</TR10>
      <Modifier>1</Modifier>
   </Parent2>
</Parent1>
```